# Is there any node modules or any system that removes Unused CSS to Reduce the Size of Style-sheets?

Tags: javascript, css, ide, editor, node-modules

I want to remove all of the unused CSS classes from my stylesheet before I push my project to the server! But I don't find any shortcut way to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on how complex your project is and what way to usage classes in markup it is using. For simpler ones, something from the tools listed here can be helpful https://www.keycdn.com/blog/remove-unused-css. If your project is more complex, and if classes are created in the JS part on the flight, and then used, there might be no way to do clean up automatically